# When does std::format throw an exception?

Tags: c++, windows, c++20

I am using `OutputDebugStringA()` to output diagnostic info from my program that I can read with `DbgView`.

Today I am using `std::stringstream` to format messages:

```
int value = 5;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "value=" << value;
OutputDebugStringA(ss.str().c_str());
```

This is rather verbose and I am looking into using `std::format()` instead:

```
int value = 5;    
OutputDebugStringA(std::format("value={0}",value).c_str());
```

which seems nice.
My only worry is that `std::format` may throw an exception.
But under which circumstances?

It would be really bad if some diagnostic or error checking code I write itself throws an exception that messes up the execution of my program.

EDIT:
example that throws an exception:

```
std::string s = std::format("value={},{}", value);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My only worry is that `std::format` may throw an exception. But under
> which circumstances?

From [[format.err.report]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/format.err.report):

> **Formatting functions throw `format_­error` if an argument `fmt` is passed
> that is not a format string for `args`.** They propagate exceptions thrown
> by operations of `formatter` specializations and iterators. Failure to
> allocate storage is reported by throwing an exception as described in
> [[res.on.exception.handling]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/res.on.exception.handling).

In short, [`format_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format_error) will be thrown when your format string is not valid for format arguments.

Comment: Thank you. It seems too easy to shoot myself in the foot with this (see my example above) to use this for diagnostic output.

Answer (score 1):

According to cppreference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format

> Throws std::bad_alloc on allocation failure. Also propagates exception thrown by any formatter.

The million dollar question: when is `std::bad_alloc` thrown??

Again in the doc:

> std::bad_alloc is the type of the object thrown as exceptions by the allocation functions to report failure to allocate storage.